# Can I get the child view of the item clicked in a list adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to attach a generic onitemclicklistener to an array list, there are 3 elements in each row of the listview that I want to be clickable that all do different things. I want to do something like this

custom listener

```
public OnItemClickListener customListener(){        
    OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {          
            int viewId = view.getId();              
            Log.d(app.TAG,"position " + String.valueOf(position) + " id " + String.valueOf(id));                
            switch(viewId){
                case R.id.tvPromote:
                    //promote text view hit             
                    break;
               case R.id.tvComment:
                    //comment text view hit             
                    break;
            }               
        }
    };      
    return listener;
}
```

Which I set in my activity earlier on like this

```
        feedArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(this, feedArray);
        listFeed.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
        listFeed.setOnItemClickListener(customListener());
```

but thew view clicked is always just the layout for the entire row, I want to get the specific element clicked.

I know I can attach onviewclicklisteners to specific elements within the array adapter but I need to access methods within the activity which starts to get pretty hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Clicks are delegated by the parents `onTouch` listener, so they can be intercepted there. The code you'll need will vary depending on your project, but a boolean can be returned to let the system know there are still unhandled events to take care of. `True` will let it know that you've consumed the event and `false` if it still needs taken care of.

Using the default source code is usually your best bet for consistency here.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java

[Motion Event | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)